# How to click a button from javascript in a lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript

I am attempting to fire the standard submit event from `recordEditForm` by clicking a hidden button from javascript but the below code is not working for me any thoughts?  I already attempted to use the `Document.getElementById()` so that I could use the base `.click()` event but the lightning button cannot have id as an attribute.

**Aura:**

```
<lightning:inputField fieldName="Sales_District_Lookup__c" onchange="{!c.onRecordSubmit}" />
<lightning:button 
           aura:id="submit"
           type="submit" 
           label="Save"  />
```

**Javascript:**

```
onRecordSubmit: function (component, event, helper) 
{   
    component.find('submit').click();
},
```

Comment: How do you know it's not working?

Comment: @sfdcfox through the magic of testing and getting an error

Comment: @CalvinOKeefe I would not have asked had your question included the error message. When asking, please try to include error messages and other relevant data.

Comment: @sfdcfox will do next time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `lightning:inputField` would be inside lightning base component like `lightning:recordEditForm`, why not directly call the submit method from your js `onRecordSubmit`?

```
<lightning:recordEditForm recordId="003XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" objectApiName="MyObject__c" aura:id="myForm" >

    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Sales_District_Lookup__c" onchange="{!c.onRecordSubmit}" />
    <lightning:button 
               aura:id="submit"
               type="submit" 
               label="Save"  />
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

JS code:

```
onRecordSubmit: function (component, event, helper) 
{   
    component.find('myForm').submit();
},
```

Src: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordEditForm/documentation

Comment: This answer doesn't trigger the javascript onsubmit handler and directly just submit the form to server

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a regular submit button which you can hide. I used this approach because the `submit()` method didn't fire the `onsubmit` of the `recordEditForm`.

Component code:

```
<button type="submit" name="submitForm" aura:id="submitForm" id="submitForm">Submit</button>
```

Submit code (controller / helper):

```
document.getElementById('submitForm').click();
```